# Quais são as diferenças entre WSGI, ASGI e RSGI?

Tags: python, terminologia

Quando trabalhamos com desenvolvimento web utilizando Python é comum cruzarmos com as siglas WSGI, ASGI e RSGI a cerca da interface entre os servidores web e a aplicação Python em si.

O que significa cada uma dessas siglas e quais são as principais diferenças entre elas?

Answer (score 1):

**WSGI** significa *Web Server Gateway Interface*, é uma especificação que já existe a algum tempo, descrito principalmente em https://peps.python.org/pep-3333/ (sendo melhor que o PEP333). Mesmo havendo diversas diferenças, a principal talvez seja a idade, pois até aonde foi descrito, aparentemente não é descrito nada sobre suportar HTTP/2, não quer dizer que as implementações baseadas nele não tenham algum meio próprio de faze-lo.

**ASGI** significa *Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface* se "declara" o sucessor espiritual do WSGI, só que assíncrono e trabalha com escopos (como se pudesse ter mais de um environ) (existem muitas implementações populares baseados nele) e suporta o HTTP/2

**RSGI**

O ASGI, citado antes, tem como foco a linguagem Python (não sei se algo mudou hoje), o RSGI foi criado pensando em atender para resolver poder usar em servidores escritos na linguagem Rust, onde a comunicação I/O real e os componentes de encadeamento são tratados fora do interpretador Python, claro que a sua aplicação ainda pode ser Python, mas terá que ser escrito conforme a implementação.

Esse último não da pra falar muito, porque até aonde vi alguém usando foi com o servidor *Granian*, o que posso afirmar é que essa implementação especifica tem pouco mais de um ano e provavelmente não é algo muito usado, ainda.

---

Não vou ficar afirmando qual é melhor ou pior, muitas coisas são cenários específicos, e existem diferentes implementações que usam a mesma interface, e podem apresentar resultados diferentes, como performance ou até limitações diferentes, mas de qualquer forma segue um benchmark, comparando os 3 (do autor do Granian), pode ser visto em: https://github.com/emmett-framework/granian/tree/master/benchmarks#granian-benchmarks